# Detect drag event of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get notified of UITableViewCell move start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898388/how-to-get-notified-of-uitableviewcell-move-start-and-end)

I have implemented a `UITableView` with a custom design. This `UITableView` has to support edit mode. When entering the edit mode, `UITableViewCell` gets decorated with additional controls (EditControl, ReorderControl...). They don't fit well with my custom design and that's why I wanted to replace their images. For that purpose I subclassed `UITableViewCell` and overrode `layoutSubview`, where I replace the images for those controls.

Problem: When starting a drag & drop operation, the image for EditControl is replaced back to the original one somewhere in UITableViewCell. I can replace it again in

```
– tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:
```

when user moves the draggable cell to another indexPath, but that's too late.

So my question boils down to: **How can I detect the moment the user actually starts dragging a `UITableViewCell`?**

Comment: use PanGesture to detect the moment of dragging operation of the images

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Already tried that, without success. I can attach a GestureRecognizer to the contentview of the cell and my handler get's fired. But it doesn't get fired for touches of the ReorderControl. The same is true for overriding touchesBegan...

Comment: Post your Code that might help to find a solution :)

Comment: I already found two solutions. First one: the images for EditControl won't be replaced by UITableViewCell, when the cell is in selected state. So i keep that state selected all the time and implemented my own tracking of selection in touchesBegan... Second and preferred solution: Dump that ugly hack, it's relying on too much internals which might change. If you are still interested I could post the hacky solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Bala's comment went into the right direction, I initially had some problems with the right implementation. Now I found out how it can be done. In short: You have to create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Override `layoutSubviews` to attach a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to `UITableViewCellReorderControl`. Define a protocol and use a delegate to inform whoever you want to about the dragging state.

CustomTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate;

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CustomTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)CustomTableViewCell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell isDragging:(BOOL)value;
@end
```

CustomTableViewCell.m:

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [_delegate CustomTableViewCell:self isDragging:YES];    // Dragging started
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [_delegate CustomTableViewCell:self isDragging:NO];     // Dragging ended
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass ([view class]) rangeOfString:@"ReorderControl"].location != NSNotFound) {    // UITableViewCellReorderControl
            if (view.gestureRecognizers.count == 0) {
                UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
                gesture.cancelsTouchesInView    = NO;
                gesture.minimumPressDuration    = 0.150;
                [view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Be aware that while this code doesn't use any private APIs it still might stop working if Apple changes its internal implementation (i.e. by changing the classname of `UITableViewCellReorderControl`).