# iOS 7 UITableView default separator gets weird after reordering

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with the default separator on `UITableView` in iOS 7.

When used as default the first and last separators have no insets, others are a bit inset. The original situation can be seen below:

[image: Everything is OK]

Everything is ok. The first and last separators spread through the entire width of the table while the others are a bit smaller. Now I have the table view set to `editing` and I allow the user to reorder cells. And when the user does so the separators get messed up and do not appear correctly. The situation can be seen on the images below:

[image]
[image]

Do I really need to reload the data in order to fix this issue or is it an iOS 7 bug or am I doing something wrong?

How to fix this?

**EDIT**
Added some info about my implementation. I return `NO` on `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` on `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. My `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont someFont];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor randomColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [color set];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);

    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return cell;
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    if (sourceIndexPath.row == destinationIndexPath.row) return;

    NSString *tmp = [itemOrder objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [itemOrder removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [itemOrder insertObject:tmp atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    didReorder = YES;
}
```

Comment: it happens cause you are recycling the cells, you would need to reload data first :)

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand you, when am I supposed to reload data? Is that good practice?

Also which is better? To use a new cell each time or to reload data?

Comment: please, post your table view delegate code

Comment: When you are moving the cell the recycled one is moved, so it moves the entire cell with the differente separator, you need to reload data after moving the cells so the large separators stay into the correct place...

Comment: If I reload the data immediately after the `moveRowAtIndexPath` gets called it flicks the cell and it looks ugly. If I do the `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` it feels like I'm hacking. Is this really the proper way to fix this issue?

Comment: @Majster check my answer.that's perfect and short solution for that.

Comment: how do you instantiate the 1st cell with long separator?

Comment: FYI: this bug has been **fixed in iOS 8**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try forcing inset size or setting them to zero in the `viewDidLoad` to ensure `tableView` respects them.

This is going to set your `tableView` separator insets to 30.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)];
    }
}
```

You can also set separator insets only on specific cells as:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellId"];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
       [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)];
    } else {
       [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I do not want the inset on inner cells to be zero, I want it to be as it is and to appear properly after moving.

Comment: I changed my answer, you can set them to anything you want. Just change 30 to your desired number.

Comment: Well this makes all insets the same. I want the first and last one without insets and others inset, just the way iOS makes it by default. I want is for the table to stay the way it was before moving (separators of course).

Comment: Well, in that case you can set them on individual cells then `[cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0)];` I've updated my answers to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem in the iOS SDK. One way to solve it would be to manually apply the correct separator insets to all cells. However, I personally prefer to let the system do that.

If you reload a cell after reordering, the correct separator insets will be applied by the system. Therefore, you should simply make sure to reload the relevant cells after reordering.

### Fix for user reorderings

There's a private method [`tableView:didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854018/251760) that's called on your table view's delegate after the reordering (animation) has ended. In this method you should reload the cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

This fix only works if rows are only moved within a section (and not between sections).

(It would be more efficient to only reload the moved cell and the cell at the old location using the method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. However, you'd have to store the old location before the cell is moved. which would be more complex to implement. For small sections/simple cells reloading the whole section might be a little bit easier.)

### Fix for programmatic moves

Unfortunately, the private delegate method used in the previous fix is only called after reorderings by the user, and not after programmatically moving a row (using `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`). Therefore, we'll have to use another fix for that.

Since table views [internally use `CALayer` animations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516056/251760), we can use a `CATransaction` to get to know when the animation has ended. (You do need to add `QuartzCore.framework` to your project for this.) My fix looks like this:

#### UITableView+NicelyMoves.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITableView (NicelyMoves)

- (void)nicelyMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                     toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath;

@end
```

#### UITableView+NicelyMoves.m

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "UITableView+NicelyMoves.h"

@implementation UITableView (NicelyMoves)

- (void)nicelyMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                     toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        // This is executed after the animations have finished
        [self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath, newIndexPath]
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }];

    [self moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];

    [CATransaction commit];
}

@end
```

#### Usage

Now, instead of using `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, you should use the custom method `nicelyMoveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. For example, you could do this:

```
#import "UITableView+NicelyMoves.h"

@implementation YourTableViewController

- (void)moveTheRow
{
    // Move row 0 to 2 in section 0
    NSIndexPath *from = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *to = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView nicelyMoveRowAtIndexPath:from toIndexPath:to];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is not working on iOS 8. Still can't find solution.

Comment: @SlavcoPetkovski It still works fine on iOS 8 in the app I built this fix for. Are you sure you've implemented it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is working now, since I was using fetchedResultsController and he was hiding the checkmarks after refreshing him. So I'm not refreshing now and it is working fine. By refreshing I mean reloading the sections.