# Saving Order on UITableView data

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I have created a reorder-able `UITableView`. I am loading data from **Realm**, and showing that data into `UITableView`. My `UITableView` has *Section* and *rows*.

now User can hold Any cell in any section and can reorder them in 2 ways

1. User can reorder cell with in the same section.
2. User can reorder cell across the different section.

**What I need:**

> Once the user has made the order he should see same item in same order
>   when he come back to App. For any type of reordering I have to do
>   indexing. But I do not have clue how to reorder them in database.

**My Idea to resolve the requirement**

My idea is to include the String type value in the Model where I can replace something like (1,10) that will indicate section 1, row 10.

But I do not have idea how to tackle this and how to save the reordering as i need here. Any idea about that?? please share

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get notified of UITableViewCell move start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898388/how-to-get-notified-of-uitableviewcell-move-start-and-end)

Comment: Why don't you keep the section and the row within the database and get your list of data ordered by these values?

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp did asa you said already and solved in that way. My only confusion was how to save in DB in real time