# Events when changing order in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am implementing changing order functionality in my UITableView. I've already set `MyTableView.Editing = true;`.

I wonder if there is an event/method saying that I've started moving the row and an event saying that I ended it up?

I've already checked: `BeginUpdates()`, `EndUpdates()` and they don't look like working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898388/how-to-get-notified-of-uitableviewcell-move-start-and-end

Comment: I test those functions and found there seems no function for you to detect when starting moving the row.

Answer (score -1):

In `UITableview`, `UITableViewDelegate` will receive the following methods when reordering actions:

```
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didCancelReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In swift may be following will help

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: looks like those methods are not officially supported. I don't like to risk being rejected during Apple's review

Comment: objective c was reference but swift  code i mentioned is supported.

Comment: I can agree that moveRowAt is called when reordering is finished but canMoveRowAt is not called when reordering starts